# How to interpret drastic differences in significance? (Environmental Kuznets Curve, panel data)

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am working on my thesis about the Environmental Kuznets Curve for Latin America and Southeast Asia, with a pannel data with fixed and random effects. I am using logarithmics and robust standard errors. I would to assess the difference in the effects between the two regions.

I obtain the results attached in the pictures. I do not understand why the cubic terms lose all their significance when adding the Latin America regional dummy and interacting it with the GDPpc variables. In the first regression (the one without regional variables), the introduction of the cubic term makes all the variables significant, and in the second regression is the opposite. How does this make sense?

Depedendent variable: ln of CO2 per capita

[image: Basic Regression for 1960-2018]
[image: Basic Regression, regional effects for 1960-2018]

Thanks in advance.

These are the codes I used in Stata:

```
est clear 
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc, fe robust 
est store fe_model
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc, re robust 
est store re_model

eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2, fe robust 
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2, re robust 
est store re_model1

eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 ln_gdppc3, fe robust 
est store fe_model2
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 ln_gdppc3, re robust 
est store re_model2
 
esttab using "a", replace  ///
 b(3) se(3) nomtitle label star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) ///
 booktabs  ///
 title("Basic regression table, 1960-2018 \label{reg1}")   ///
 // addnotes("Data: websuse nlswork" "Second line note")
```

```
est clear 

eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc LAgdppc, fe robust 
est store fe_model
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc Latin_America LAgdppc, re robust 
est store re_model

eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 LAgdppc LAgdppc2, fe robust 
est store fe_model1
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 Latin_America LAgdppc LAgdppc2, re robust 
est store re_model1

eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 ln_gdppc3 LAgdppc LAgdppc2 LAgdppc3, fe robust 
est store fe_model2
eststo: xtreg ln_co2pc ln_gdppc ln_gdppc2 ln_gdppc3 Latin_America LAgdppc LAgdppc2 LAgdppc3, re robust
est store re_model2

esttab using "prueba.tex", replace  ///
 b(3) se(3) nomtitle label star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) ///
 booktabs  ///
 title("Basic regression table, regional effects for 1960-2018 \label{reg1}")   ///
```